# Normalized steepest descent with nuclear/frobenius norm

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, matrix, gradient

In steepest gradient descent, we try to find a local minima to a loss function $f(\cdot)$ by the rule:

$x_{t} = x - \alpha \triangledown_{x}f(x)$.

I've found in textbooks that often we want to normalize the gradient subject to some norm such as the $l_2$ norm, where the above equation becomes:

$x_{t} = x- \alpha \frac{\triangledown_{x}f(x)}{||\triangledown_{x}f(x)||_{2}}$.

My question is, how would this equation change if I wanted to normalize the gradient subject to a different norm, such as the nuclear norm or the Frobenius norm? Would the resulting update rules simply be:

$x_{t} = x- \alpha \frac{\triangledown_{x}f(x)}{||\triangledown_{x}f(x)||_{*}}$.

$x_{t} = x- \alpha \frac{\triangledown_{x}f(x)}{||\triangledown_{x}f(x)||_{F}}$.

respectively, for the nuclear norm and Frobenius norm? I couldn't find much information on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention: $x$ in this case is an m by n real-valued matrix.